# Elasticsearch count number of nested object list (java)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have an index which contains a nested list:

```
class A {
    String id;
    List<B> b;
    //plus other parameters
}
```

(**important**: id is not unique)

I need to aggregate all docs by `id` and calculate the number of `b`s per `id`.

I'm using `org.elasticsearch.client` version 5.6.2 .

This is aggregation part of my code:

```
AggregationBuilders.terms("id").field("id")
     .subAggregation(
         //THIS IS WHERE I HAVE PROBLEM!
         AggregationBuilders.nested("b", "b")
     )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searches, I found `Inner hits` and I think this is the only way.

According to [elastic community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/count-nested-documents-only/113248):

> Using nested `inner_hits` you can get the count of documents that
>   are nested inside your top-level documents. However, you won't get a
>   total count for the whole result set, you need to iterate over each
>   hit and sum up the nested count on the client side.